# VPN on a Bridged Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, security, virtual-machine, vpn, privacy

If one would use a VPN service on a bridged virtual machine running Linux on a Windows host, would the connection's security and privacy be breached in any way or shape due to this situation or would the system behave completely independently form host's unsecured connection?

Answer (score 1):

From a networking POV it would be independent - ie the packets traversing the VM host would be encrypted.

From a security POV, if the host is compromised it could read, write.and manipulate memory in the VM, which, among other things means it could theoretically get the keys, intercept and MITM or otherwise acquire data.

This would be robust against "joe hacker" and protecting your porn viewing habits, but maybe not against the NSA or equivalent. (of-course they can likely get you more easily other ways). Remember that a VPN only"apparently moves" the traffic origin point - unless you control both sides it can be intercepted between VPN server and wider Internet, only protected by an obfusicated address and different routing path.